# Sinon spy on console.log call not registered

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I'm trying to learn about Sinon and want to spy on `console.log`. The code is simple:

```
function logToConsole() {
    console.log('Hello World');
}

exports.logToConsole = logToConsole;
```

But if I want to test it, it doesn't work because the call to `console.log` is not registered inside the system under test:

```
var chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect,
    sinonChai = require('sinon-chai'),
    sinon = require('sinon'),
    sut = require('../src/logToConsole');

chai.use(sinonChai);

describe('logToConsole', function() {
    it('should spy on console.log', function() {
        sinon.spy(console, 'log');

        sut.logToConsole();

        expect(console.log).to.have.been.called;
    });
});
```

However if I execute `console.log` inside the test itself, it is captured and passes:

```
it('should spy on console.log', function() {
    sinon.spy(console, 'log');

    sut.logToConsole();
    console.log('Test');

    expect(console.log).to.have.been.called;
});
```

Interestingly, it doesn't seem to be able to spy on inner-function calls at all. Is this not the purpose of a spying library?

e.g.

```
function a() {};

function b() {
    a();
}
```

Answer (score 24):

It looks like you're not actually using `sinon-chai`, the code you post is missing this line:

```
chai.use(sinonChai);
```

**EDIT**: here is the code I tested with:

```
// test.js
var chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect,
    sinonChai = require('sinon-chai'),
    sinon = require('sinon'),
    sut = require('./log');

chai.use(sinonChai);

describe('logging', function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    sinon.spy(console, 'log');
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    console.log.restore();
  });

  describe('logToConsole', function() {
    it('should log to console', function() {
      sut.logToConsole();
      expect(console.log).to.be.called;
    });
  });

  describe('logToConsole2', function() {
    it('should not log to console', function() {
      sut.logToConsole2();
      expect(console.log).to.not.be.called;
    });
  });
});

// log.js
module.exports.logToConsole = function() {
  console.log('Hello World');
};

module.exports.logToConsole2 = function() {
};
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to write it in my question, but it doesn't change a thing.

Comment: This will output 'Hello World' to the test console - how to hide that?

Comment: @maasha not easily, I'm afraid. The issue is that Mocha itself also uses `console.log()` for output, so if you disable `console.log()` (for instance, by stubbing it instead of spying on it), you will lose (part of) Mocha's test output as well.

Comment: Another reason to never use `console` directly. Instead, use a logger library or function so you can just stub that.

Comment: @StijndeWitt And what if you are making a isomorphic logging library for browser and node... You can't just shove the problem down the road, that's bad practice.

Comment: @KarlMorrison He he that's the one exception I guess :)